# Pentaho table input step with large data running in parallel

Tags: mysql, pentaho, transformation, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am relatively new to Pentaho. I am working on a Job with 35 Transformations running in parallel, each of the transformation is reading around 1Million data from a MySQL DB and storing into another database(MSSQL).

But it fails within few minutes and it shows : `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

I wanted to know how can I ease this process and if there is any way to read the data in a batch wise method or can I use a loop in the transformation so that the data is read in a chunk (say 5000) in each transformation.

Also, what will be the best way to read large data from a Table when so many transformations are run in parallel. And how does the "Nr of Rows in Rowset" value impacts the performance for huge data.

I tried a few things from the forum but didn't get any noticeable improvements.

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?160467-how-to-improve-performance-of-Table-input-Table-output-step
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?85626-Kettle-4-2-0-Stable-Table-Input-does-full-table-read
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?59364-Optimum-Nr-of-Rows-in-Rowset

Please let me know if I can share anymore details for better explanation.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you tried running each single transformation by itself? There might be just one that has huge data fields or some step that consumes all memory. If all of them finish without error running alone, you can start adding more together and see when it starts to fail.

Answer (score 4):

I've used PDI in the past in similar scenarios, though with different databases.

With straight table copies or simple row-level transforms, I've never had memory issues. One big difference was that I used a single transformation with 20 table inputs each connecting to their own table output. Perhaps the overhead is lower that way.

As far as I understand, each hop in a transformation represents a row buffer that by default holds up to 10k rows. These are visible in the metrics as the input/output buffers of the steps and are kept in memory. This means that the bigger the rows and the more steps you have, the more memory you need.

For the most basic case (table input -> table output), you will have one 10k row buffer. If the rows average 100 bytes, you will need more than... 1 MB.
If you have 11 steps (10 buffers) and a row size of 32kb, you might need more than 3.2 GB if all the buffers fill up.

There are also special case steps that need to keep a lot of rows or even all rows before they can start outputting rows. Group By, Sort, Blocking Step are examples. Some of them have the ability to write intermediate data to disk, others don't. Avoid these in bulk operations or pay special attention to their data stream to optimize it.

If your destination database can't keep up (a common scenario because writes are more expensive), all the buffers can fill up quickly. Having so many transformations writing to the database at once may also affect performance.

There are many aspects to optimizing this kind of operation so I can't list them all, but these have solved issues for me in the past:

- Increase the number of rows per commit, this may improve throughput at the destination database.
- Increase the Java Heap (-Xmx option in the startup file).
- Do sorting in the source database.
- Do grouping in the database if it's good at that (MySQL gave me bad results).
- If you have many steps before a table output and the buffers are full, split the transformation. Put a text file output in place of the table output as these are usually lightning fast. In the second transform you only put text file input and table output.

Comment: yup, just increase the Xmx. The default is very very low.